# Oracle - Match_recognize /\ shape detect

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching, oracle12c

sample data from https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_EG95N4HMCYSL1A0Y6J80UHNHB.html

Based on this data and visualization, there is 2 /\ shape's:

[image]

1st - from 1.05 to 06.04

2nd - from 06.04 to 12.04

and this query shows 2nd as 07.04 to 12.04:

[image]

I'm new in Oracle Match_recognize, and i am wondering - why is that?

Comment: I think `lead()` and `lag()` is much simpler in this case.

Comment: I think if i would like to use lead and lag - i would... but this question is about match_recognize, not lag/lead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` does not allow the same row to be in different matches. If you want the last value in one match to be the first value in the next match, you need to modify the `AFTER MATCH SKIP` clause.

[image]

The default setting is `AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW`. Adding the code `AFTER MATCH SKIP TO LAST DOWN` to your query will give the results you want.

See [this db<>fiddle for a runnable example.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd466adb321cabd9b0d5a3a55c249355)